# Which sub-string Javascript method should I use for maximum compatibility & performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, substring

I thought about using `substr()` with a negative start number to extract the last character of a string. But [on w3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp), it says that it's not compatible with IE8:

> To extract characters from the end of the string, use a negative start number (This does not work in IE 8 and earlier).

I've also read that there are performance problems.

So I decided to use the method below, which works, but is it best practice, best for compatibility and good for performance?

```
q = 'Hello there!'

console.log(q.substring(q.length - 1, q.length));

// logs '!'
```

Comment: Where and what did you read about performance problems?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `slice`. It can be used in IE8 afaik:

```
q = 'Hello there!'
console.log(q.slice(-1)); //=> "!"
```

[**See also**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Or use the `substr` [**shim**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_%28computing%29) presented [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr#Description)

Concerning performance see [**this page**](http://www.konpik.com/2012/01/26/cross-browser-javascript-string-functions/)